# Can I use the Input::all() outside Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, facade

I've inherited a project that was 'plain' php i.e. it didn't use a Framework or other dependencies. I've been working on integrating [Eloquent](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent) and [Ardent](https://github.com/laravelbook/ardent) (for self-validating models).

I've installed them using composer and all seems to be working well. I have a folder called Models and I load the classes using a bootstrap type file:

```
$loader = require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Illuminate\Database\Capsule\Manager as Capsule;
use Illuminate\Events\Dispatcher;
use Illuminate\Container\Container;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;

$capsule = new Capsule;

$capsule->addConnection([
    'driver'    => 'mysql',
    'host'      => '127.0.0.1',
    'database'  => '*********',
    'username'  => '*********',
    'password'  => '*********',
    'charset'   => 'utf8',
    'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    'prefix'    => '',
]);

$capsule->setEventDispatcher(new Dispatcher(new Container));

// Make this Capsule instance available globally via static methods... (optional)
$capsule->setAsGlobal();

// Setup the Eloquent ORM... (optional; unless you've used setEventDispatcher())
$capsule->bootEloquent();


// Autoload all the models
spl_autoload_register(function ($class) {
    include 'models/' . $class . '.php';
});


LaravelBook\Ardent\Ardent::configureAsExternal(array(
  'driver'    => 'mysql',
  'host'      => '127.0.0.1',
  'port'      => 3306,
  'database'  => '************',
  'username'  => '************',
  'password'  => '************',
  'charset'   => 'utf8',
  'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci'
), 'en'); //English is the default messages language, may be left empty
```

However, whenever I try to use Input::all() it causes the following error:

```
 Call to a member function all() on a non-object in /home/loadbay/public_html/beta/php-bin/vendor/illuminate/support/Facades/Facade.php on line 207
```

I'm assuming it's something to do with Facades and I'm not sure how to get this working. Can someone help me understand how I can use Input::all() please?

**Update**

Line 207 of Facade.php:

```
return $instance->$method();
```

Comment: which laravel you are using 4.2/5?

Comment: I'm using Laravel 5 compatible components.

Comment: You cannot use that without using Laravel service container. Input facade is trying to fetch $request instance from the container and call all() on this but there is no container initialized in your script.

Comment: I suspected the service container might be the cause of this. Is there any way I can set up a container? I'm new to the concept of containers so I'm a little bit stuck.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using the `Input()` facade, you could try just creating the `Request` directly:

```
$request = \Illuminate\Http\Request::capture();
$input = $request->all();
```

It would be nice to have a `Container` to hook all this together, but I don't have that information for you right now.